# Asp.Net Identity is hosted both on Github and CodePlex. Which one is the official one?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, open-source, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

As I search for the source code of Asp.Net Identity, the project can be found on both github and codeplex. The problem is that both seem to be the main repository.
Which one is the correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identity officially hosted on both **Github** and **CodePlex**.

You'll be find asp.net identity **version 2.x** source code in **CodePlex** but **GitHub** contains the latest source code which is **version 3**, part of **ASP.NET vNext**.

Also you'll find that there are number of differences in the **version 2.x** and **version 3**. **Microsoft.AspNet.Indentity.Core** and **Microsoft.AspNet.OWin identity** parts combined into one project named Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.